# Struggling to display data I am trying to insert on webpage

Tags: python, html, django

I am currently doing CRUD with Products model and I am having a hard time displaying the data that I am trying to insert.

model

```
class Products(models.Model):
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    sub_categories = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    # image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/',width_field=None,height_field=None,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    sku_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    prod_details = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    isactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

show and insert function

```
def show(request):
    showall = Products.objects.all()
    print(showall)
    serializer = POLLSerializer(showall,many=True)
    print(serializer.data)
    return render(request,'polls/product_list.html',{"data":serializer.data})
```

```
def insert(request):
    if request.POST == "POST":
        print('POST',id)
        insert_clothes = {}
        insert_clothes['categories']=request.POST.get('categories')
        insert_clothes['sub_categories']=request.POST.get('sub_categories')
        insert_clothes['color']=request.POST.get('color')
        insert_clothes['size']=request.POST.get('size')
        # insert_clothes['image']=request.POST.get('image')
        insert_clothes['title']=request.POST.get('title')
        insert_clothes['price']=request.POST.get('price')
        insert_clothes['sku_number']=request.POST.get('sku_number')
        insert_clothes['product_details']=request.POST.get('product_details')
        insert_clothes['quantity']=request.POST.get('quantity')
        form = POLLSerializer(data = insert_clothes)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print('data',form.data)
            print(form.errors)
            messages.success(request,'Record Updated successfully :)!!!!')
            return redirect('polls:show')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        print('GET',id)
        return render(request,'polls/product_insert.html')
```

html page of insert and show respectively

```
<form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Categories</td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="categories">
                                <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                                <option value="1">9-6 WEAR</option>
                                <option value="2">DESI SWAG</option>
                                <option value="3">FUSION WEAR</option>
                                <option value="">BRIDAL WEAR</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sub-Categories</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="sub_categories" placeholder="SUB_CATEGORIES">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Colors</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="color" placeholder="Enter Colors">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Size</td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="size">
                                <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                                <option value="SM">SM</option>
                                <option value="M">M</option>
                                <option value="L">L</option>
                                <option value="XL">XL</option>
                                <option value="XXL">XXL</option>
                                <option value="XXXL">XXXL</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Title</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter title">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the price" name="price">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>SKU Number</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="sku_number">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>product_details</td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="product_details" cols="30" rows="10">

                            </textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>quantity</td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter the quantity"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Insert" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {% if messages %}
                            {% for mess in messages %}
                            <b style="color:green;">{{mess}}</b>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
            <button class="btn btn-success"><a href="{% url 'polls:show' %}" style="color: red;">Go To Home</a></button>

        </form>
```

```
{% for result in data %}
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><b>{{result.categories}}</b></td>
          <td><b>{{result.sub_categories}}</b></td>
          <td><b>{{result.color}}</b></td>
          <td><b>{{result.size}}</b></td>
          <td><b>{{result.title}}</b></td>
          <td><b>{{result.price}}</b></td>
          <td><b>{{result.sku_number}}</b></td>
          <td><b>{{result.prod_details}}</b></td>
          <td><b>{{result.quantity}}</b></td>
          <td style="position: relative;left:50px;">
            <a href="/product_edit/{{result.id}}/">
              <button class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i>
              </button>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="/Delete/{{result.id}}/" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure you want to delete?')">
              <button class="btn btn-danger">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
              </button>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      {% endfor %}
```

I have checked the namings as well and I am still having a hard time figuring out why I am unable to display the code that I am trying to insert

Comment: Why are you using a serializer instead of a model form? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/

Comment: I am told to use serializers instead of forms

Comment: Is the data actually saved in the database or are there any errors?

Comment: the data isnt getting displayed in the database as well,when I use forms.data,it shows empty array

Comment: hers what the compiler shows 

"POST /insert/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5631
<QuerySet []>

Comment: Is `POLLSerializer` a `django-restframework` `ModelSerializer`?

Comment: yes POLLSerializer is a django resframework ModelSerializer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246273/discussion-between-janmalte-and-tapeplixio).

Answer (score 0):

In your insert view it should be `if request.method =='POST':`

```py
def insert(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # ... your code
```

Comment: hi jan I have done that but the data still isnt visible